# How to copy a folder from inside the Jenkins container to a location outside the Docker container using a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I installed jenkins image using docker.

The deploy directory exists.But I am getting an error "/var/www/jenkins-simple-nuxt does not exist"
So, How to **copy** the folder from **inside the Jenkins container** to a location **outside the Docker container** using the **Jenkins pipeline**

```
pipeline {
     agent any
     tools {
        nodejs 'mp-16.2.0'
     }
     environment {
        DEPLOY_DIR = '/var/www/jenkins-simple-nuxt'
     }
     stages {
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                sh "npm install"
                sh "npm run build"
            }
        }
        stage("Deploy") {
            steps {
                sh "cp -r ${WORKSPACE}/.nuxt/* ${DEPLOY_DIR}/"
                sh "chown -R www-data:www-data ${DEPLOY_DIR}"
                sh "chmod -R 755 ${DEPLOY_DIR}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```